# Create a 4x7 table using an array and fill up the array with random values

Tags: java, python

1. Create a 4x7 table using an array and fill up the array with random values.
2. Then find the column number (X) where the last row contains the smallest value.
3. Then find ratio_1, ratio_2, ratio_3 where

   - ratio_1 = the value from last column of 1st row / the value from column X of 1st row
   - ratio_2 = the value from last column of 2nd row / the value from column X of 2nd row
   - ratio_3 = the value from last column of 3rd row / the value from column X of 3rd row

Notice that, X is the column number that you find in step 2.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Post the code which you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import random
data = [
    [int(random()*10) for j in range(7)]
    for i in range(4)
]
```

Output

```
data = [
    [2, 7, 8, 9, 8, 1, 1],
    [5, 7, 0, 9, 1, 8, 6],
    [6, 5, 8, 3, 7, 4, 8],
    [2, 5, 4, 0, 9, 8, 7]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from random import random

grid = [[], [], [], []]

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(7):
        grid[x].append(random())


last_numbers = [grid[0][6], grid[1][6], grid[2][6], grid[3][6]]
column_number = last_numbers.index(max(last_numbers))

ratio_1 = grid[3][0] / grid[column_number][0]

ratio_2 = grid[3][1] / grid[column_number][1]

ratio_3 = grid[3][2] / grid[column_number][2]
```

Comment: is it answer for all 3 ques